# Как сделать поиск по тэгу?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт с камерой которая следует за персонажем, она ищет по типу, а мне надо по тэгу. Подскажите как это сделать.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 2.0F;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!target) target = FindObjectOfType<Тэг персонажа>().transform;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 position = target.position;         position.z = -10.0F;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я ж ответил в прошлом вопросе(зачем снова спрашивать) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705606/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bc

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Камера не следует за персонажем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705606/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: @Xumera_hZ надо было в ответ писать тогда. дублем нельзя закрыть, так как вопрос задан в предыдущем о другом, даже не смотря на то, что в итоге было порекомендован поиск по тегу. Ну и ответа там нет. Проще тот вопрос удалить, чтоб не болтался как кое-что в проруби))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по **[документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)** так:

```
if (target == null) {
    var go = GameObject.FindWithTag("MyCharacterTag");
    target = go.transform;
    // или просто:
    // target = GameObject.FindWithTag("MyCharacterTag").transform;
}
```